# How can I run docker-compose start in foreground?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

How can I start services with docker-compose start in foreground like docker start -a  does?

Comment: `docker-compose up your_servicename`, docker-compose up will start in the foreground.

Comment: I think this question was correct, worth for upvote, not downvote. But the answer I think was not correct. If you hit the `docker-compose up` then it runs at the foreground, you can see immediately the container logs and you get back the prompt only if you hit the  `CTRL + c`. The `docker-compose start` command runs in the background and you get back the prompt immediately after you hit enter. If you want to see the log then you must use an additional command: `docker-compose logs -f`. I think the question addressed this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`docker compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) command already run all containers in foreground by default:

> The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each
>   container (essentially running `docker-compose logs -f`). When the
>   command exits, all containers are stopped.

The only exception is when using the `-d` flag:

> Running `docker-compose up -d` starts the containers in the background
>   and leaves them running.